# KCL Verification

Tags: voltage

I'm practicing problems for circuits class. Did I write these KCL equations properly? If not, where did I mess up?

Note: on the attached schematic, I'm solving for things in terms of their identifier and not their value, so I marked all the values for R and C as 0. Vp and V0 are node voltages. The voltage controlled current source is gmVp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE5Af0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to verify if you entered a schematic via the editor and typed out the equations.

Comment: @uint128_t done

Comment: Even more easier if you specified actual component values instead of 0 ohms and 0 Farads

Comment: @Bart there are no component values specified. Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

The nodal equations are correct.